# xwatermark and draftmark packages stopped working

Tags: draftwatermark, xwatermark

I've been using `xwatermark` and `draftmark` without problem until today, when LaTeX documents I created using both stopped compiling to PDFs.  I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 using TL 2014, which I installed myself last week.

Here's a test document, which compiles correctly when the `xwatermark` code is commented out.  The failed compilations (those calling `xwatermark`) create a `.WMX` file that must be deleted before the commented-out version will compile.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}


\usepackage{fixltx2e, amsmath, fancyhdr, fancyvrb, lastpage, supertabular, xymtex, chemist, bpchem, graphicx, graphics, longtable, array, setspace, supertabular, epsfig, calc, ifthen, mhchem, chemfig, siunitx, chemmacros} 

 \usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

 \newwatermark[allpages,fontfamily=pag,color=gray!25,angle=45,scale=5, xpos=-30,ypos=20]{DRAFT}

\fancyhf{}
\lfoot{\vspace{16pt} Attorney Docket No.:~***}
\rfoot{\vspace{16pt} Page \thepage \ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.5in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.1in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}

\DeclareSIUnit\cal{cal}
\DeclareSIUnit\Molar{\textsc{M}}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{1.5}

What is claimed:

\begin{enumerate}
  \item  Blah

  \item  Blah blah

  \item Blah blah blah


\end{enumerate}

\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

I've seen two errors.  One is this:

```
ERROR: Argument of \Hy@setref@link has an extra }.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.49 \end{document}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

The other is this:

```
\xwm@secstopagerange {1000}{1}
```

I'm flummoxed.  I updated TL (2014) today.

Comment: It worked with TL 2014 before the update? By the way, you should definitely not be loading all of those packages. (They are unnecessary for you MWE but some of them are also unnecessary for your document. You do not need both `graphics` *and* `graphicx`, for example.) It does compile OK here with not-quite-current TL. I'm updating now to test.

Comment: I just updated TL and it still seems to compile fine. Even when I delete the `aux` and `xwm` files, it recompiles fine with current TL 2014.

Comment: Thanks, Gonzalo.  I agree with your point about the number of packages, but this is a template I use and I hadn't gotten around to cleaning it up.  And as I wrote, it worked prior to the update yesterday.  Unfortunately, even if I delete all of the packages except for xwatermark I get a new error: ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
<argument> ...e \@tempdima \@parboxrestore \color 
                                                  {\wmk@textcolor }\cptdimde...
l.25 \end{document}